# Generate a weekly email for each user based on role, who have custom opportunity objects that meet a criteria

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, email-template

I've got a custom object "Invoices" tied to my Opportunities, so Opps have 1 or more invoices. Each invoice has a "date to be sent" field.

What I'd like to do is auto-generate an email every Monday morning that notifies each User of their Opportunities and with Invoices scheduled to go out < Next 7 Days. The purpose is for them to go in and edit the Invoice to either flag is as "Ok to send" or to move the date back to a more appropriate time.

I'm trying to accomplish this using a VisualForce email template, but can't for the life of my figure out if the relatedTo should = User or Opportunity since I want it to list all of the relevant invoices for Opportunities owned by the User.

Anyone have any guidance on how best to implement something like this?

Adding in some code from VF Email.

```
messaging:emailTemplate subject="Review Invoices" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity"    

//then the loop for invoices
apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Invoice__c}"

//show this stuff in a table. Can use outputtext to skip if date is out of range
{!relatedTo.name}
{!cx.Invoice_name__c}
{!cx.Invoice_amount__c}

/apex:repeat
```

This code isn't finding the invoice__c object, and I've tried all kinds of variations. Can't seem to find an easy reference for how object elements relate via API name anywhere.

Comment: relatedTo = Opportunity;

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but can't seem to use an apex:repeat value that cycles through all invoices for each opportunity. Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: you should be able to , I;'ve done similar things before ..post your VF email template -- relevant bits only

Comment: Relatedto.invoices__r is what you need

Comment: Thank you! That worked. 2 quick follow ups, if possible. 1) How did you derive the number Invoices__r. The only reference I can see is the Plural name of the object? 2) Now that it's tied as a template to the opportunity, is there any way to pull in all opportunities? That was why I was confused between starting with relatedTo=User or Opportunity

Answer (score 1):

Your line `apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Invoice__c}"` would be an invalid field if Opportunity is a parent of Invoices. In Salesforce, a custom relationship is typically (default) named as plural of child sobject appended by `__r`.

Hence, the apex:repeat should be:

`apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Invoices__r}"`

Standard relationships don;t use the `__r` convention, for example, the relationship from Account to Contacts is defined as `Contacts`, the relationship from Account to Opportunities is `Opportunities`.  You can find the relationship names by examining the schema (specifically, the metadata property `childRelationships` for any SObject.

You had a follow-on question:

> Now that it's tied as a template to the opportunity, is there any way to pull in all opportunities? That was why I was confused between starting with relatedTo=User or Opportunity

An email template's context depends on how it is invoked:

- If invoked as an email alert from a workflow or flow, then the template applies only to a single target object instance.
- If invoked by a `sendEmail()` Apex method, the template also applies only to a single object instance, the one specified by the `setWhatId(...)` method

To get all Opportunities onto a single email to a user, you will need to use a custom VF component with associated controller that will query all Opportunities and their child Invoices for a given user. The custom component exists inside of a VF email template where the `relatedToType=User` and you'll pass the `relatedTo.id` as a parameter to the custom component

```
<c:myCustomComponent_opposAndInvoices userid="{!relatedTo.id}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to try to wrap my head around this and get it going. Really appreciate all the help.

Comment: one line got omitted from my post

Answer (score 0):

think  value="{!relatedTo.Invoice__c}"  should be  value="{!relatedTo.Invoice__r}"  as  value="{!relatedTo.Invoice__c}" is the ID not the relationship.